# dynamically inserting non english(hindi) in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, insert

I've been given a project to work on wherein i need to create a Database that can store and retrieve non english data. I've looked up and made all my connections to UTF. however,everytime it inserts into the DB,and the no. of rows get incremented but i only get blank fields in my DB.

---

```
<html>
<body>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">


<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');

mysql_select_db('Hindi',$con);

$nith = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `HINDI` (
`data` varchar(1000) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin default NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

if (!mysql_query($nith,$con))
{
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }

$Name = $_POST['Name'];

$nithi = "INSERT INTO `HINDI` 
     "(Name) ".
     VALUES ('$Name')";

if (!mysql_query($nithi,$con))
{
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
  /*
 $result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");//the main trick
 $cmd = "select * from HINDI";
 $result = mysql_query($cmd);
 while($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result))
 {
 echo ($myrow[0]);
 }
*/
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Employee Name</td>
<td><input name="emp_name" type="text" id="emp_name"></td>
</tr>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add Employee">
</td>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made the changes suggested below but now instead of blank values,i get &#2951;&#2984;&#3021;&#2980;&#3007;&#2991;&#3006;



i want it to get stored as its equivalent value- இந்தியா in the database as well..

pls help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you change **Collation** to **utf8_general_ci** in your database table ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be making it troublesome for you is the charset encoding of your PHP documents. If they are encoded in ASCII (some text editors create documents like this as standard) it will not work properly.

You could download [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for free and open your document, go to encoding and if your document isn't UTF-8, select convert to UTF-8 without BOM. Do this with all of your PHP documents.

Comment: I also see that you have `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";` change this to `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";`

Comment: I have used notepad++ as the text editor for the coding and i converted it to UTF-8 without BOM..but it still isn't helping. I still get blank values in the DB

Comment: I just saw that the PHP code reads the wrong value. `$Name = $_POST['Name'];` Change this to `$Name = $_POST['emp_name'];` because your HTML Code has 
'<input name="emp_name" type="text" id="emp_name">` written.
name="emp_name" is what $_POST[''] reads

Comment: Oh! thanks a lot,i completely didnt see that! 
Btw,i made that change and now it gets inserted in the DB as well :)
however,it gets stored as &#2951;&#2984;&#3021;&#2980;&#3007;&#2991;&#3006; 

i want it to get stored as its equivalent value- இந்தியா 

pls help!

Comment: I think it is because your table has `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1` If you can, drop(delete) the table named HINDI and change it to `CHARSET=utf8` and create the table again. And if that doesn't work, try to change it to `CHARSET=utf8mb4`. This is what i usually use, it's a version of utf8 that supports more characters.

Answer (score 0):

Check what rdanusha and quncage have asked.

Also check whether your php file is utf-8 encoded.

Also add accept-charset="utf-8" in your form attributes.

For example
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_accept_charset.asp

Comment: The php file is converted to UTF-8. 
and i added accept charset in the form tag,still no help.
i still get blank values in the DB

Comment: Have you converted the table definition to utf8. If it does not work try converting to utfm64 if I remember correctly. Also your table create will not change an existing table becuase of create if not exists clause.  Manually drop. Change the charset in create and then try.